# Can I use the zoom functionality of UIWebView to just make the HTML text size grow? And not lose any content off the sides?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, uiwebview, zooming

I have a UIWebView that I am using to display pretty simple HTML. When I enable Scales Pages to Fit, I can pinch and zoom and its pretty cool. But the problem is that it isn't an "intelligent" zoom. It just zooms in on wherever I am pinching, and the content that doesn't fit just gets pushed off the side of the page. So in order to see that you end up doing the side scroll thing.

Is it possible to redraw the content as I zoom? So that instead of just zooming, it actually makes the text bigger and intelligently makes it all fit on the screen?

I can achieve this by changing the HTML font size, but the slider is kind of clunky. I want to make this awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do this using javascript that will look more fine than changing font size for the HTML.

Comment: Not extremely versed in Javascript, can you expound a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following method, I've tried it by making a category of UIWebView, so here self means instance of UIWebview

```
-(void)setFontSizeWithValue: (float)fontSize
{
   NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%f%%'",(fontSize * 10.0)];
  [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
  [jsString release];
}
```

hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a hybrid solution, which means detect the users pinch and zoom gestures and based on that change that html font size.

You will have to customize UIwebView and implement [UIResponder delegates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> – touchesBegan:withEvent:
>
> – touchesMoved:withEvent:
>
> – touchesEnded:withEvent:
>
> – touchesCancelled:withEvent: